# How to synchronize files with Ubuntu One automatically as soon as they are sent to the provided directory

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

How can I synchronize my files in the cloud with Ubuntu One? It used to be authomatic, but it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

It should just work automatically in all supported platforms. If it doesn't, please [contact support](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/).

Comment: Knowing which one of these conditions you are dealing with would help answer the question.

1. If you click "Synchronize this folder" in nautilus, it will begin syncing that folder _on that computer only_.

2. On another computer, the above folder will not automatically start syncing. You will need to select it under the Cloud Folders tab in the Ubuntu One Control Panel.